# GCP Layer3 Load balancer

Tags: networking, load-balancing, google-cloud-platform

I'm looking for a way to load balance (LB) **layer3** network traffic with GCP. Off the shelf [GCP load blancers](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/load-balancing-overview#traffic_type) support only down to layer4 (TCP/UDP). I would like to find the most GCP native solution for this in order to minimise management orchestration.

My question split into two:

1. Is this possible to obtain using **only** the current GCP features (Using the GCP API) ?

**If not**

2. What is a good alternative for implementing and managing a layer3 load balancer when using a cloud service platform (the solution can be hybrid or agnostic to GCP) ?

Note:
I tried using iproute2 with ECMP to implement the LB but its hard to managing when you start scaling up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your first question, GCP doesn't provide any L3 Load Balancing solutions at the moment. I would suggest filing a [Feature Request](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers) . Note that there's no ETA for its availability or guarantee of implementation.

Regarding your second question, I would recommend consider using a third party software like [HAProxy](https://www.haproxy.org/download/1.4/doc/configuration.txt), [NGINX](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/load-balancer/tcp-udp-load-balancer/) or check other available options in [GCP Marketplace](https://cloud.google.com/marketplace/docs).

Comment: Tnx for the replay. Sadly I have came to the same conclusion after a long research.

Answer (score 0):

In case at this point in time anyone has this question, GCP now offers network load balancing, natively as a cloud service.

Here is the [official documentation.](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/network/networklb-backend-service)